# HTML tables attributes

Tags: html, html-table

Can any one help me that:
Is axis and axes attributes of html tables are allowed in HTML 5?
Example:.
`<table><tr><td axes="abdul" axis="name">I am Abdul Wasay</ td></tr></table>`

Comment: Please, if it answered your question, marked my answer as the solution to help future users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they were last supported in HTML 4.01: https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-axis-attribute.php